# Physical intuition behind torque converter

Tags: fluid-dynamics, torque

A [torque converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torque_converter) (also [here](http://web.mit.edu/2.972/www/reports/torque_converter/torque_converter.htm)) is a device used in some cars. It uses several "fans" coupled through a liquid (transmission fluid) in order to perform the function of a clutch, but more importantly it acts as a liquid gear in the sense that it multiplies the torque going from the engine to the wheels.

Is there an intuitive way to explain what is happening in the liquid? In particular, is it possible to explain the torque multiplication effect without resorting to numerical analysis?

Comment: Have you checked out if one of the manufacturers of torque converters provides a better explanation? Those links seem mediocre at best...

Comment: @solarmike, you want to furnish the answer, or let me take a crack at it?

Answer (score 3):

A torque converter contains a propeller that is spun by the engine and another close by which is connected to the rest of the transmission. these two propellers face each other in a chamber filled with oil, so that when the engine-driven prop spins, it pumps oil through the second prop and causes it to spin as well.

Between these two props is a disc with blades in it which catches the oil after it has passed through the second prop, and diverts its flow back around to the engine-driven prop which then picks up that return oil and pumps it into the second prop again.

This disc is cleverly designed so the return oil flow strikes the engine-driven prop blades at such an angle that the energy contained in the return flow adds to the energy being pumped into the flow by the engine-driven prop, in an amount proportional to the difference in rotating speed (called the *slippage*) between the engine-driven propeller and the second prop.

Recovering the energy in the return flow multiplies the torque force exerted on the second prop by as much as ~3X in the high-slip limit where the second propeller is standing still and the engine is running at speed (which is called the *stall torque* condition)- as they would be when you put your foot on the gas from a standstill.

In the limit where both props are running at roughly the same speed (the no-slip condition), the torque multiplication factor falls to ~1X.

The action of that extra disc of blades is the key element in getting torque multiplication during the slip condition and is the hardest thing to grasp in the operation of a torque converter!

Comment: Just to complement your answer (plus 1 btw), here is a link to the video by Allison : https://www.floridatorqueconverters.com/torque-video.html

Comment: Thank you @solar mike!

Comment: I guess we agree that the velocity triangles won't help here :)

Comment: Hi guys, real cool stuff, thanks for the explanation here and the link to the video. However, I am still not getting what is going on in the liquid. I can but agree that "The action of that extra disc of blades is the key element in getting torque multiplication during the slip condition and is the hardest thing to grasp in the operation of a torque converter!". I hoped for some physical intuition, eg, in terms of expanding Euler equations or something, or what happens to the flow lines in the stall torque situation.

Comment: Am I right in understanding that what the torque converter is doing is storing energy (which was not transferred to the output fan) in the momentum of the moving liquid, and when this re-strikes the fan, it provides an additional force on the input fan on top of the torque applied by the input shaft? So it is, in a manner, a sort of liquid flywheel, in which any slip between the fans causes energy to be transferred into the momentum of the circulating transmission fluid, and this then discharges again by striking the input fan a second time on its opposite side?

Comment: you should not think of the torque converter as an energy storage device. it is an energy *transfer* device, and your description of it above is essentially correct.

Comment: Well of course the unit as a whole is designed to transfer energy, I just hadn't understood until now how the "torque multiplication" occurred - the energy is stored in the momentum of the circulating fluid, which (if not discharged by inducing rotation of the output fan) is then redirected back around and re-presented a second time against the output fan (together with a further input of momentum from the input fan). It's an amazing principle of operation!

Comment: Could not agree more with Steve! The magic of torque multiplication is presumably in how the fluid couples to the turbines.

Answer (score 1):

Check this video below that perfectly describes the operation of torque converters.

[Fluid Coupling: Principles of Operation (1953)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bQEaBI7qFlw)

Torque converters (TC) are defined by a torque ration, which is in turn defined by the turbine design withing the converter. There are two turbines, as described in the video. If you make a TC out of two identical turbines you will get 1:1 ratio. The torque remains the same. This is very similar to the operation of the [transformer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformer).

However, if you change the design of the output turbine so that is increases or decreases the torque (this is done by changing the number and/or shape of turbine blades) you will get different torque ratios too.

One turbine propels the fluid and serves as a pump. The other turbine is driven by the moving fluid. In this way, two turbines in TC are coupled by the liquid. BY changing the design of secondary turbine you can make changes in the value of the output torque. Read [Euler's pump and turbine equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_pump_and_turbine_equation).

Comment: The video unfortunately does not seem to be available any more.

Answer (score 1):

To me, this is by far the most understandable video that explains this mechanism:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bRcDvCj_JPs&feature=emb_rel_pause

To summarize, the torque multiplication is the result of the reactor that helps the pump increase the oil pressure. When the difference of speed between the pump and the turbine is high, the reactor derivates the oil flow in the same direction as the pump. The energy unused by the turbine is thus given back to the pump, which increases the torque. When the turbine speed and the pump speed are near, the reactor starts spinning, and the torque multiplication ceases.

Comment: Many thanks, Guerric. A very slick and well produced video, I especially appreciate the visualization of the flow of the fluid. The actual torque multiplication part starts at 4:51 https://youtu.be/bRcDvCj_JPs?t=291 .